# how to integrate pullToRefresh in android studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I'm new in gradle and android studion.I made integration from eclipse my project (via export )to gradle project.Almost all libs are compiled fine just one pushToRefresh list don't want to add.Every time gradle show me error like this

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller than version 4
```

Please help me to solve this issue.There also my gradle code from main project

```
    apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    repositories {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':google-play-services_lib-mycity')
    compile project(':view-paget-indicator-mycity')
    compile project(':facebook-sdk-mycity')
    compile project(':Android-PullToRefresh-master:extras:PullToRefreshListFragment')
    compile project(':Android-PullToRefresh-master:library')

    }
}

android {

    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add to the `build.gradle` these lines after `buildToolsVersion`:

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 4 //or your minsdk
    targetSdkVersion 19
}
```

Gradle overrides some values in your Manifest, for example the minSdk.
If this value is not specified, gradle uses the value = 1 (and the pulltoRefresh library uses minSdk=4)

Comment: yeah.This is helped me.Thanks